# iOS Storyboard Passing Data

Tags: ios, storyboard

Is there anybody who can help a beginner?

I've got two storyboards, the first has a button and the second has a label. I want to push the button and I want the label to display the text.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
second *myVC = segue.destinationViewController;
myVC.mylabel.text = @"Why isn't this working!!";
}
```

The button acts as the segue.

I would also like to add that I've checked everything and I'm puzzled as to know why it's not working. I would have expect it to work, so if someone could also explain what I'm doing wrong or missing I'd be very grateful.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In prepareForSegue: your second view does not exist yet. The output of mylabel is not connected with the view. Create a new NSString property in your second controller. Set it in prepareForSegue: and use it to setup the label in viewDidLoad: of the second controller.